# Custom configuration section with keys and an attribute

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config

I need to make a config section like appsettings but with an attribute on the surrounding element, eg:

```
<userSettings>
    <machine name="my-machine">
        <setting key="Site" value="http://localhost" />
        <setting key="Online" value="true" />
    </machine>
    <!-- more machines -->
</userSettings>
```

I have the collection of machines and collections of settings working ok as per examples, but I can't get the name attribute on machine to work in conjunction with settings collection.

Here is my Machine class

```
public class Machine : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            // This line doesn't compile, cannot convert SettingElement to string
            return (string)this["name"]; 
        }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new SettingElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((SettingElement)element).Key;
    }

    // this method is the problem but I want to be able to do 
    // something like 
    // section.Machines[Environment.MachineName][settingKey].Value
    public new SettingElement this[string index]
    {
        get { return (SettingElement)BaseGet(index); }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(BaseIndexOf(BaseGet(index)));
            }
            BaseAdd(value);
        }
    }
}
```

And Setting

```
public class SettingElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("key", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string Key
    {
        get { return this["key"].ToString(); }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("value", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this["value"].ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you create a new xml file rather than making use of config file.
if you use xml file , it will be hell lot easier to manage and manipulate

Comment: Really not helpful...